# Why is my DataFrame not callable for .values()?

Tags: python

```
data1 = pd.read_excel('Fatigue Current.xlsx')
data_num1 = data1.values()
```

> Error  data_num1 = data1.values() TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is
> not callable

Comment: `values` is not a method but a property so lose the brackets, just `values`

Comment: accept my answer please if it helped

Answer (score 0):

Do this to get the values.

```
data1 = pd.read_excel('Fatigue Current.xlsx')
data_num1 = data1.values
```